# Build APP using specific keys via Phonegap Build API?

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to use [Phonegap Build API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/developer-api/write/).

I am using this open source PHP library to connect to the Phonegap plugin.

https://github.com/mradionov/phonegap-build-api

Everything works fine as it should.

I can add keys, upload apps and all other general tasks.

However, the issue that I currently have is that I need to be able to upload the app and build it using a specific key for each platform.

To upload the app I use this method:

```
$res = $api->updateApplicationFromFile(3334534, 'path/to/myapp.zip', array(
  'title' => 'The APP title',
  // see docs for all options
));
```

This uploads it correctly and as it should.

Now, i tried to upload the app using the same method but select a specific key to build it with like so:

```
 $res = $api->updateApplicationFromFile(3334534, 'path/to/myapp.zip',
  'title' => 'The APP title',
  'keys' => 1435671
  // see docs for all options
));
```

But this fails to do anything and I dont see any errors either!

Based on the Phonegap API documentation, we can send the following to the API:

```
keys":{"ios":123,"android":567,"winphone":72}
```

the numbers used are the keys/certficates that already uploaded onto the Phonegap system.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

finally found it.

Basically I need to pass the values as an array like so:

```
'keys' => array("ios" => XXXXXXX, "android" => XXXXXXXX),
```

So the code looks like this:

```
 $res = $api->updateApplicationFromFile(3334534, 'path/to/myapp.zip',
  'title' => 'The APP title',
  'keys' => array("ios" => XXXXXXX, "android" => XXXXXXXX),
  // see docs for all options
));
```

And this works just fine...

Hoep this helps others.